# How can I connect to the internet using a pppoe account in Sabayon Linux?

Tags: linux, pppoe

I recently downloaded Sabayon Linux 4.2 Gnome Edition. I burned a dvd and started the live version. I tried to configure a pppoe account like I do in most Linuxes, using the pppoe-setup/pppoeconf command, however, no pppoe commands show up in bash's shell tab completion.

How can I configure my pppoe connection in Sabayon ?

Comment: I (and probably most of the community here) have never heard of that Distro. Maybe they have a forum where you can ask this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sabayon should come with a pppoe-setup command. After following the instructions you should be able to run pppoe-start and get internet access.

As sleske said, you may not have the net-dialup/ppp package by default. If you don't you may be out of luck, unless you can find some other, temporary way to connect to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if no pppoe commands show up, maybe pppoe software is not installed ;-) ?

On Gentoo, you install the software with

> emerge net-dialup/ppp

Maybe try that?

Comment: Can I perform that command with no internet access?

Comment: I don't know (don't know Gentoo very well), probably not, but there are certainly other methods. Don't know the specifics, though.

Comment: It depends on whether Gentoo has the source (or install) files downloaded already, or on the install CD/DVD. If the files exist locally, you would not need to connect to the internet. If the files do not exist locally, you need to be connected to the internet. If you are not sure, try the command and it will tell you if it needs the net connection.